# Watchman quits unexpectedly

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, watchman

I am using visual studio code along with react-native and expo. Whenever I run `expo start` It says in the terminal 
`hemlatamahaur@Hemlatas-MacBook-Pro IFN666Skeleton % expo start
Starting project at /Users/hemlatamahaur/Desktop/IFN666 React Native Skeleton 2/IFN666Skeleton
Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
Could not get status from Metro bundler. connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:19003
Connecting to Metro bundler failed.`

I am not sure why it says cannot connect to metro bundler. 
All I did at starting was used `npm start` to install dependcies and expo install to install expo related things, and now I just used `expo start` and I get all those errors.

And another tab opens and it says `watchman quit unexpectedly` with the error as below:

```
Process:               watchman [52733]
Path:                  /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/xdl/binaries/osx/watchman/watchman
Identifier:            watchman
Version:               0
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           watchman [52733]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2020-06-08 16:14:17.744 +1000
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.3 (19D76)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        5E60E708-09F1-861C-2676-771B031905FB

Sleep/Wake UUID:       6D39217C-7A22-4830-8A11-D813016F177E

Time Awake Since Boot: 300000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       16000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        8

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6f89c896 poll + 10
1   watchman                        0x000000010fcfd4e7 w_start_listener + 1159
2   watchman                        0x000000010fcfef57 run_service + 695
3   watchman                        0x000000010fcfe15f main + 431
4   libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff6f7557fd start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6f8b63b2 __sigsuspend + 10
1   watchman                        0x000000010fce8b7d child_reaper + 157
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6f95ee65 _pthread_start + 148
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6f95a83b thread_start + 15

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6f898ce6 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6f95f185 _pthread_cond_wait + 701
2   watchman                        0x000000010fd04aef state_saver + 127
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6f95ee65 _pthread_start + 148
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6f95a83b thread_start + 15

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6f898ce6 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6f95f185 _pthread_cond_wait + 701
2   watchman                        0x000000010fcfb14c fsevents_root_wait_notify + 156
3   watchman                        0x000000010fd01a6f run_notify_thread + 207
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6f95ee65 _pthread_start + 148
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6f95a83b thread_start + 15

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6f89625a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6f8965d0 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff38000890 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 322
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff37fff456 __CFRunLoopRun + 1705
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff37ffe738 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 503
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff38086c4d CFRunLoopRun + 40
6   watchman                        0x000000010fcfb41c fsevents_thread + 300
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6f95ee65 _pthread_start + 148
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6f95a83b thread_start + 15

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6f95a818 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6f898ce6 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6f95f185 _pthread_cond_wait + 701
2   watchman                        0x000000010fceed9b w_pending_coll_lock_and_wait + 139
3   watchman                        0x000000010fd0121f run_io_thread + 575
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6f95ee65 _pthread_start + 148
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6f95a83b thread_start + 15

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6f89c896 poll + 10
1   watchman                        0x000000010fcf06ea w_poll_events + 234
2   watchman                        0x000000010fcfd8f3 client_thread + 179
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6f95ee65 _pthread_start + 148
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6f95a83b thread_start + 15

Thread 8 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6f89c7fa __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6f95ebc1 pthread_kill + 432
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff6f823a1c abort + 120
3   watchman                        0x000000010fcea8d8 w_log + 776
4   watchman                        0x000000010fcea08b check_my_sock + 155
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6f95ee65 _pthread_start + 148
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6f95a83b thread_start + 15

Thread 8 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000700004e2f000  rcx: 0x0000700004e2ab68  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x000000000000187f  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x0000700004e2ab90  rsp: 0x0000700004e2ab68
   r8: 0x00007fa142100000   r9: 0x00007fa142118f80  r10: 0x0000700004e2f000  r11: 0x0000000000000246
  r12: 0x000000000000187f  r13: 0x00000000ffffffff  r14: 0x0000000000000006  r15: 0x0000000000000016
  rip: 0x00007fff6f89c7fa  rfl: 0x0000000000000246  cr2: 0x0000700004e26978

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000148
Trap Number:     133


Binary Images:
       0x10fce6000 -        0x10fd18fff +watchman (0) <5E540A25-B8E3-3188-AD04-0B8992FAD3B5> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/xdl/binaries/osx/watchman/watchman
       0x111c49000 -        0x111cd9cb7  dyld (733.8) <EBC07CB6-870A-3A8E-B48A-67F62EA161F3> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff33c09000 -     0x7fff33c09fff  com.apple.Accelerate (1.11 - Accelerate 1.11) <479607C6-EE4F-3471-BCFD-9A8677A509A3> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
    0x7fff33c21000 -     0x7fff344c8fc7  com.apple.vImage (8.1 - 524.2) <3A01D6DE-219E-3038-AE1D-98F0703996F4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
    0x7fff344c9000 -     0x7fff34662fef  libBLAS.dylib (1303.60.1) <331A9933-58D7-3575-A1B2-4255755FA645> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
    0x7fff34663000 -     0x7fff34869fff  libBNNS.dylib (144.40.3) <2432B08E-3DE5-3910-A0E5-0C68AF055E0C> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBNNS.dylib
    0x7fff3486b000 -     0x7fff34c1ffff  libLAPACK.dylib (1303.60.1) <0918AC5B-DC2D-3878-90F9-4E16C4302FAB> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
    0x7fff34c20000 -     0x7fff34c35ff8  libLinearAlgebra.dylib (1303.60.1) <A5F9CB86-1D36-330C-BD98-310D924FC1C2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
    0x7fff34c36000 -     0x7fff34c3bff3  libQuadrature.dylib (7) <E0534024-B7E7-3382-830C-71E7BD9D3DE4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libQuadrature.dylib
    0x7fff34c3c000 -     0x7fff34cacfff  libSparse.dylib (103) <533DFAE8-8458-31F4-8AE2-B73C3869CED2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libSparse.dylib
    0x7fff34cad000 -     0x7fff34cbfff7  libSparseBLAS.dylib (1303.60.1) <EEC8A3FF-4DD2-3447-A6D9-5DFA716B767E> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libSparseBLAS.dylib
    0x7fff34cc0000 -     0x7fff34e52fc7  libvDSP.dylib (735.40.1) <0C40F97B-FD6C-3324-91DC-947266F2A502> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvDSP.dylib
    0x7fff34e53000 -     0x7fff34fcdff7  libvMisc.dylib (735.40.1) <2AC65C58-463C-31D0-A130-040EFFE4792E> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvMisc.dylib
    0x7fff34fce000 -     0x7fff34fcefff  com.apple.Accelerate.vecLib (3.11 - vecLib 3.11) <22118F7C-4019-32CE-B8AF-50FFBF9BC050> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
    0x7fff36709000 -     0x7fff36a95ff6  com.apple.CFNetwork (1121.1.2 - 1121.1.2) <4E539AC8-A995-3BA8-AAD6-31D97DAE734B> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
    0x7fff37f7c000 -     0x7fff383fcfff  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 1674.114) <9A91AEBF-6DA4-3238-870F-452FBD170EEA> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff39390000 -     0x7fff39390fff  com.apple.CoreServices (1069.11 - 1069.11) <3BBDA17B-6F86-35F4-B785-AFA2A14B6F51> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
    0x7fff39391000 -     0x7fff39416fff  com.apple.AE (838 - 838) <877C7270-575A-3D5F-B768-4724037F025D> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE
    0x7fff39417000 -     0x7fff396f8ff7  com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore (1217 - 1217) <DDC45E79-973C-3FB0-92EC-392A654179F5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
    0x7fff396f9000 -     0x7fff39746ff5  com.apple.DictionaryServices (1.2 - 323.3.1) <A21D442C-E7B7-3A6C-BEEC-44B323AF9CB2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/Versions/A/DictionaryServices
    0x7fff39747000 -     0x7fff3974ffff  com.apple.CoreServices.FSEvents (1268.60.1 - 1268.60.1) <8C772593-A2BA-33A7-BB43-49B9FCDD37CE> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/FSEvents.framework/Versions/A/FSEvents
    0x7fff39750000 -     0x7fff39989ff0  com.apple.LaunchServices (1069.11 - 1069.11) <7189EED9-9252-3030-AB32-6704AD9AEBAE> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices
    0x7fff3998a000 -     0x7fff39a22ff9  com.apple.Metadata (10.7.0 - 2075.7) <AECD1E1F-1C1B-3C42-9ACD-596980F145C2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
    0x7fff39a23000 -     0x7fff39a50ff7  com.apple.CoreServices.OSServices (1069.11 - 1069.11) <67A2F664-DCA1-3FD6-B88E-CF020EA8C59D> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Versions/A/OSServices
    0x7fff39a51000 -     0x7fff39ab8fff  com.apple.SearchKit (1.4.1 - 1.4.1) <367BBFA7-F18C-34B6-B4C8-A244A125D5E0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Versions/A/SearchKit
    0x7fff39ab9000 -     0x7fff39addff5  com.apple.coreservices.SharedFileList (131.4 - 131.4) <EB8F2B1B-B736-373F-B28B-E4E6F33A00C0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SharedFileList.framework/Versions/A/SharedFileList
    0x7fff3a32d000 -     0x7fff3a333fff  com.apple.DiskArbitration (2.7 - 2.7) <5BE0B036-DEAB-3191-8D44-B489F4D39EE1> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
    0x7fff3a665000 -     0x7fff3aa2dffc  com.apple.Foundation (6.9 - 1674.114) <532BBAE7-F2BA-3779-94E0-BFEDF2D7AB38> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
    0x7fff3ada5000 -     0x7fff3ae48ffb  com.apple.framework.IOKit (2.0.2 - 1726.80.1) <B63FE840-8E32-3429-A95D-AB466FE62104> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
    0x7fff3e6b2000 -     0x7fff3e6beffe  com.apple.NetFS (6.0 - 4.0) <0B2088AE-C16D-3FC3-9445-4EDAD2D51686> /System/Library/Frameworks/NetFS.framework/Versions/A/NetFS
    0x7fff41284000 -     0x7fff412a0fff  com.apple.CFOpenDirectory (10.15 - 220.40.1) <FF068FF7-C136-3A71-AD1F-B5170A918423> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFOpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/CFOpenDirectory
    0x7fff412a1000 -     0x7fff412acff7  com.apple.OpenDirectory (10.15 - 220.40.1) <9448EC8E-8B76-3142-9540-C0752529762A> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/OpenDirectory
    0x7fff445f7000 -     0x7fff44949ffa  com.apple.security (7.0 - 59306.80.4) <FA5EBA16-2B2B-3105-8A17-C8624C4B3BB3> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
    0x7fff4494a000 -     0x7fff449d3ff7  com.apple.securityfoundation (6.0 - 55236.60.1) <0129932D-89E5-3608-B22E-DB5F0B3C3DC4> /System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityFoundation.framework/Versions/A/SecurityFoundation
    0x7fff44a02000 -     0x7fff44a06ff0  com.apple.xpc.ServiceManagement (1.0 - 1) <2475707B-F909-33C4-AAB7-80DC8D2CB435> /System/Library/Frameworks/ServiceManagement.framework/Versions/A/ServiceManagement
    0x7fff45799000 -     0x7fff45803fff  com.apple.SystemConfiguration (1.19 - 1.19) <61B73150-6D87-3E2F-A935-B957425CC992> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
    0x7fff4956e000 -     0x7fff49632fe7  com.apple.APFS (1412.81.1 - 1412.81.1) <7EC14196-E481-35C0-94F0-09E5B81AD3E5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/APFS.framework/Versions/A/APFS
    0x7fff4b2ad000 -     0x7fff4b2bcfef  com.apple.AppleFSCompression (119 - 1.0) <EEDA4040-1835-39A6-AC13-6CE35560C159> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleFSCompression.framework/Versions/A/AppleFSCompression
    0x7fff4ca64000 -     0x7fff4ca6dff3  com.apple.coreservices.BackgroundTaskManagement (1.0 - 104) <D0F2851A-521F-335A-B7C4-B1E39BB42DD7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackgroundTaskManagement.framework/Versions/A/BackgroundTaskManagement
    0x7fff4f834000 -     0x7fff4f844ff3  com.apple.CoreEmoji (1.0 - 107) <544182E2-893F-3975-AA70-26ADC637B3F1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreEmoji.framework/Versions/A/CoreEmoji
    0x7fff4fe98000 -     0x7fff4ff02ff0  com.apple.CoreNLP (1.0 - 213) <287973D6-1807-3A81-8F57-7BB39209F6C0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreNLP.framework/Versions/A/CoreNLP
    0x7fff50b21000 -     0x7fff50b4fff7  com.apple.CSStore (1069.11 - 1069.11) <26602CC8-0080-3E85-A588-79CEF78D21E5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreServicesStore.framework/Versions/A/CoreServicesStore
    0x7fff5cc69000 -     0x7fff5cd37ff5  com.apple.LanguageModeling (1.0 - 215.1) <B47A62F3-7F45-3A84-A856-C674D4613261> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LanguageModeling.framework/Versions/A/LanguageModeling
    0x7fff5cd38000 -     0x7fff5cd80ff7  com.apple.Lexicon-framework (1.0 - 72) <CD6D3F05-0647-348D-AED0-9566F968A954> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Lexicon.framework/Versions/A/Lexicon
    0x7fff5cd87000 -     0x7fff5cd8bff2  com.apple.LinguisticData (1.0 - 353.6.1) <91C3132C-EB52-32D6-9009-DE4B207ACE72> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LinguisticData.framework/Versions/A/LinguisticData
    0x7fff5e0e6000 -     0x7fff5e132fff  com.apple.spotlight.metadata.utilities (1.0 - 2075.7) <F7FA0F68-7E46-3461-9DA6-C55FBB85C799> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MetadataUtilities.framework/Versions/A/MetadataUtilities
    0x7fff5ebe6000 -     0x7fff5ebf0fff  com.apple.NetAuth (6.2 - 6.2) <A400CD55-B3EA-371A-8BAB-FDDA87660AE4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetAuth.framework/Versions/A/NetAuth
    0x7fff67978000 -     0x7fff67988ff3  com.apple.TCC (1.0 - 1) <A8308EDB-9AF7-3B6B-AAC3-143F91F58F1D> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/Versions/A/TCC
    0x7fff6bbf9000 -     0x7fff6bbfbff3  com.apple.loginsupport (1.0 - 1) <F2EC9213-901A-3657-A36A-DFD80BD8ABBC> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/login.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/loginsupport.framework/Versions/A/loginsupport
    0x7fff6bf5c000 -     0x7fff6bf91ff7  libCRFSuite.dylib (48) <31D98527-9972-3A4B-9868-C9394FAF742E> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
    0x7fff6bf94000 -     0x7fff6bf9eff3  libChineseTokenizer.dylib (34) <9E2B02B0-32A5-3245-AC50-F6BEEC34FCEC> /usr/lib/libChineseTokenizer.dylib
    0x7fff6c02b000 -     0x7fff6c02dff7  libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib (112) <45E85899-039F-3B99-8789-F497DD9916C2> /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib
    0x7fff6c4f3000 -     0x7fff6c4f4ff3  libSystem.B.dylib (1281) <A2C26908-8802-3CA7-8B74-ED4A74AA152C> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff6c583000 -     0x7fff6c584fff  libThaiTokenizer.dylib (3) <9E5B4E50-E982-387C-AA2F-BB43867322ED> /usr/lib/libThaiTokenizer.dylib
    0x7fff6c59c000 -     0x7fff6c5b2fff  libapple_nghttp2.dylib (1.39.2) <C79E1B79-0BBE-311F-A177-6879D5C4D991> /usr/lib/libapple_nghttp2.dylib
    0x7fff6c5e7000 -     0x7fff6c659ff7  libarchive.2.dylib (72.40.2) <1AE0592D-8451-30D1-AEE8-3F39F46D9DD4> /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
    0x7fff6c78b000 -     0x7fff6c78bff3  libauto.dylib (187) <71A48A59-FE0E-3D86-A219-B79DAF7CF9DD> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
    0x7fff6c852000 -     0x7fff6c862ff3  libbsm.0.dylib (60) <5EBEA671-D25B-3425-AC2B-70C2760B8B94> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
    0x7fff6c863000 -     0x7fff6c86ffff  libbz2.1.0.dylib (44) <FA7CE29A-2FE3-3107-8693-5D33D5B7E11F> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
    0x7fff6c870000 -     0x7fff6c8c3ff7  libc++.1.dylib (800.7) <1D0CB627-8A78-329F-A679-1B5248FF4C59> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
    0x7fff6c8c4000 -     0x7fff6c8d8fff  libc++abi.dylib (800.7) <7AF668FB-901D-3F45-BA0D-710A235A8D1F> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
    0x7fff6c8d9000 -     0x7fff6c8d9ffb  libcharset.1.dylib (59) <56F66234-104F-3494-B336-598800CF3F71> /usr/lib/libcharset.1.dylib
    0x7fff6c8da000 -     0x7fff6c8ebffb  libcmph.dylib (8) <9B9AB2BA-75FB-3B70-AAE4-E32B06CF9D69> /usr/lib/libcmph.dylib
    0x7fff6c8ec000 -     0x7fff6c904ff7  libcompression.dylib (87) <A23B412C-48BA-385A-9263-B35F7BF44F4F> /usr/lib/libcompression.dylib
    0x7fff6cbd4000 -     0x7fff6cbeaff7  libcoretls.dylib (167) <6D32CE15-591C-39AD-9A3E-0C2FFC03C3C1> /usr/lib/libcoretls.dylib
    0x7fff6cbeb000 -     0x7fff6cbecfff  libcoretls_cfhelpers.dylib (167) <3CE60FA9-98FC-3EE0-B398-177F3CAA850D> /usr/lib/libcoretls_cfhelpers.dylib
    0x7fff6d315000 -     0x7fff6d315fff  libenergytrace.dylib (21) <8E5C9BB2-14F4-37DF-AAE7-8130EBF466A3> /usr/lib/libenergytrace.dylib
    0x7fff6d33d000 -     0x7fff6d33ffff  libfakelink.dylib (149) <7296A5B3-EE44-34E6-810A-2A12C2D3EF68> /usr/lib/libfakelink.dylib
    0x7fff6d34e000 -     0x7fff6d353fff  libgermantok.dylib (24) <7B3FFFFB-5E34-3940-8E0A-B64A2DE42E68> /usr/lib/libgermantok.dylib
    0x7fff6d35e000 -     0x7fff6d44eff7  libiconv.2.dylib (59) <30414773-5E42-3976-B7C3-9BB8883792EE> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
    0x7fff6d44f000 -     0x7fff6d6a7ff7  libicucore.A.dylib (64252.0.1) <0F9294A7-6EC0-3279-BF92-3233C89DFA0A> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x7fff6d6c1000 -     0x7fff6d6c2fff  liblangid.dylib (133) <EDF945D6-A37D-3DEB-B956-B4745269603D> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
    0x7fff6d6c3000 -     0x7fff6d6dbff3  liblzma.5.dylib (16) <F75FB525-C702-3A7E-9239-28D57E677DD5> /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
    0x7fff6d6f3000 -     0x7fff6d79afff  libmecab.dylib (883.1.1) <A2C923A6-D955-3FF1-82AE-7E54947F9566> /usr/lib/libmecab.dylib
    0x7fff6d79b000 -     0x7fff6d9fdfe1  libmecabra.dylib (883.1.1) <971A30D4-1C27-3DD1-AACF-8337AE059F70> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
    0x7fff6decb000 -     0x7fff6e341ff7  libnetwork.dylib (1880.60.5) <8B4092C3-9F1C-34C3-A73D-A2228C345831> /usr/lib/libnetwork.dylib
    0x7fff6e3e0000 -     0x7fff6e412ff6  libobjc.A.dylib (781.2) <99501DBA-94BF-35A1-A85D-189A4C38CABF> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7fff6e425000 -     0x7fff6e429fff  libpam.2.dylib (25) <55302451-C2B2-3DB4-9092-B84E236104DA> /usr/lib/libpam.2.dylib
    0x7fff6e42c000 -     0x7fff6e462ff7  libpcap.A.dylib (89.60.2) <FD167BF3-6984-36E1-9D93-E8B98E3E64A1> /usr/lib/libpcap.A.dylib
    0x7fff6e558000 -     0x7fff6e739ff7  libsqlite3.dylib (308.4) <08CF1AFB-5453-36C4-8CB4-F41D2B8CA94A> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
    0x7fff6e98b000 -     0x7fff6e98effb  libutil.dylib (57) <6CB26E6D-AD27-3FA8-8A30-4AFC3A2AE3F9> /usr/lib/libutil.dylib
    0x7fff6e98f000 -     0x7fff6e99cfff  libxar.1.dylib (420) <317EA455-78EE-35A4-B63F-D85993B8697C> /usr/lib/libxar.1.dylib
    0x7fff6e9a2000 -     0x7fff6ea84ff7  libxml2.2.dylib (32.14) <4F4EB304-2AA5-3E5F-AB24-F645E0D16EFC> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
    0x7fff6ea88000 -     0x7fff6eab0fff  libxslt.1.dylib (16.7) <E9BBE609-BA57-368D-95D7-ACA3A8C1AE8B> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
    0x7fff6eab1000 -     0x7fff6eac3ffb  libz.1.dylib (76) <52250917-039C-3B46-8011-497FEACF3550> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x7fff6f527000 -     0x7fff6f52cff3  libcache.dylib (83) <11C19883-6F99-390D-AF2A-A85A99DDFC48> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
    0x7fff6f52d000 -     0x7fff6f538fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib (60165) <FEE99884-61F0-3332-852B-B0BB8EFF2288> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
    0x7fff6f539000 -     0x7fff6f540fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib (101.2) <D7367E6D-A27D-3209-A3DB-A6F44582E502> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
    0x7fff6f541000 -     0x7fff6f54afff  libcopyfile.dylib (166.40.1) <91670D15-CB30-3277-8AA9-9A299CEAAE27> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
    0x7fff6f54b000 -     0x7fff6f5e2fdb  libcorecrypto.dylib (866.80.2) <3B110D82-B403-31E8-8109-8BBC79C928CE> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
    0x7fff6f6f9000 -     0x7fff6f73aff0  libdispatch.dylib (1173.60.1) <5EF42E98-AD0D-3FAE-ABD4-46D791B8343F> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
    0x7fff6f73b000 -     0x7fff6f770ff7  libdyld.dylib (733.8) <8B0DFE8A-42CF-32C8-B121-83C22BF25F69> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
    0x7fff6f771000 -     0x7fff6f771ffb  libkeymgr.dylib (30) <7DADC026-70A8-390F-95AF-F3F345760F24> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
    0x7fff6f772000 -     0x7fff6f77eff7  libkxld.dylib (6153.81.5) <7572CC82-E7E1-3C38-825F-9B34E2EADAD0> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
    0x7fff6f77f000 -     0x7fff6f77fff7  liblaunch.dylib (1738.80.8) <C4EA8803-E506-3514-9839-9BBECC819953> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
    0x7fff6f780000 -     0x7fff6f785ff7  libmacho.dylib (949.0.1) <395ABE7C-D2B1-343D-A451-9CEA98FDC12E> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
    0x7fff6f786000 -     0x7fff6f788ff7  libquarantine.dylib (110.40.3) <560961FC-1FEF-3F07-8406-17A36558870E> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
    0x7fff6f789000 -     0x7fff6f78aff7  libremovefile.dylib (48) <E99833DE-CB1D-31AB-A948-2739AF503599> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
    0x7fff6f78b000 -     0x7fff6f7a2fff  libsystem_asl.dylib (377.60.2) <21A259BC-F892-34EB-9A67-11232AD8913A> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
    0x7fff6f7a3000 -     0x7fff6f7a3fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib (74) <8B23F806-8153-3163-B5D8-2C3327E211D8> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
    0x7fff6f7a4000 -     0x7fff6f82bff7  libsystem_c.dylib (1353.60.8) <99202CC3-2E27-3680-A8FF-5C516C485E90> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
    0x7fff6f82c000 -     0x7fff6f82fffb  libsystem_configuration.dylib (1061.80.3) <8A149700-51AA-3205-A9D4-FF2A7BFC5412> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
    0x7fff6f830000 -     0x7fff6f833ff7  libsystem_coreservices.dylib (114) <CCC076FA-310D-3FC9-950D-41E0F8DDA5D2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
    0x7fff6f834000 -     0x7fff6f83cfff  libsystem_darwin.dylib (1353.60.8) <31ACD3CC-6DD9-3F2E-B163-9342BE1D0AB0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_darwin.dylib
    0x7fff6f83d000 -     0x7fff6f844ffb  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (1096.60.2) <BEBB815A-065A-365E-9701-8E05A8CF2040> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
    0x7fff6f845000 -     0x7fff6f846ffb  libsystem_featureflags.dylib (17) <340AD606-7C39-3E6A-BAC3-EA1273FC27A4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_featureflags.dylib
    0x7fff6f847000 -     0x7fff6f894fff  libsystem_info.dylib (538) <B0EBAE05-01AD-3D8E-92CC-5704394FF94A> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
    0x7fff6f895000 -     0x7fff6f8c1ff7  libsystem_kernel.dylib (6153.81.5) <23909F45-79C3-34C9-A28F-337915925E5E> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x7fff6f8c2000 -     0x7fff6f90efff  libsystem_m.dylib (3178) <5236DC09-35C8-31A4-AE2A-92DA3DF30FE6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
    0x7fff6f90f000 -     0x7fff6f936fff  libsystem_malloc.dylib (283.60.1) <00190446-C6A8-3EA6-92D1-850EA85C84CE> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
    0x7fff6f937000 -     0x7fff6f944ffb  libsystem_networkextension.dylib (1095.60.2) <1E7A59D0-BBCD-3CB0-8AD1-D442A1A5268E> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
    0x7fff6f945000 -     0x7fff6f94eff3  libsystem_notify.dylib (241) <AB3FAC47-A830-3158-8D99-DBC728CED1D6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
    0x7fff6f94f000 -     0x7fff6f958fef  libsystem_platform.dylib (220) <3DAFCC01-B768-3FFC-AC59-47AAE86BBEA1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
    0x7fff6f959000 -     0x7fff6f963fff  libsystem_pthread.dylib (416.60.2) <AAF506F4-9455-3CC4-8E0B-6791E3C0993C> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    0x7fff6f964000 -     0x7fff6f968fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (1217.80.1) <C8F3841A-9364-3414-9E3F-9DE3D5FECF0C> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
    0x7fff6f969000 -     0x7fff6f96bfff  libsystem_secinit.dylib (62.80.1) <32F36517-9A1C-3D30-85C8-611A2F5E2355> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_secinit.dylib
    0x7fff6f96c000 -     0x7fff6f973ffb  libsystem_symptoms.dylib (1238.60.1) <2EDF9CE8-4091-30A8-B125-0F25E579694A> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib
    0x7fff6f974000 -     0x7fff6f98aff2  libsystem_trace.dylib (1147.80.3) <AE11B1AC-352A-37F0-BCA9-055609070104> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
    0x7fff6f98c000 -     0x7fff6f991ffb  libunwind.dylib (35.4) <E867ACDE-EADE-3C91-A2A4-0C401788FD47> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
    0x7fff6f992000 -     0x7fff6f9c7ffe  libxpc.dylib (1738.80.8) <51E3E807-9133-3605-BB5F-D59ED6404ABF> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 14
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 296037
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=421.4M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=421.4M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=76.0M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=76.0M(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Activity Tracing                   256K        1 
Dispatch continuations            8192K        1 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        1 
MALLOC                            55.4M       35 
MALLOC guard page                   16K        4 
STACK GUARD                       56.0M        9 
Stack                             12.1M        9 
__DATA                            5985K      120 
__DATA_CONST                        20K        1 
__LINKEDIT                       353.9M        3 
__OBJC_RO                         32.0M        1 
__OBJC_RW                         1780K        2 
__TEXT                            67.5M      120 
__UNICODE                          564K        1 
shared memory                       12K        3 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                            593.4M      311
```

Can someone please help me with that?

Comment: Have you found any solutions? I'm also having this issue.